# How to detect deadlocks in Django?

Tags: django, exception, transactions, deadlock

How to detect a transaction deadlock in Django?

Which exception it raises?

It seems for me that it is `IntegrityError` but this exception is raised also in other situations (not deadlocks). How to check if it is a deadlock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it raises [`OperationalError`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#operationalerror) if deadlock

Answer (score 0):

You can read more in django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/exceptions/#database-exceptions